# how to get email from li's span tag in python using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm placing HTML code :

```
<div class="rendering rendering_person rendering_short rendering_person_short">
  <h3 class="title"><a rel="Person" href="https://moh-it.pure.elsevier.com/en/persons/paola-alberti" class="link person"><span>Paola Alberti</span></a></h3>
  <ul class="relations email">
    <li class="email"><a href="mailto:paola.alberti@istitutotumori.mi.it" class="link"><span>paola.alberti@istitutotumori.mi.it</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="relations organisations">
    <li><a rel="Organisation" href="https://moh-it.pure.elsevier.com/en/organisations/fondazione-irccs-istituto-nazionale-dei-tumori" class="link organisation"><span>Fondazione IRCCS Istituto Nazionale dei Tumori</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="type"><span class="family">Person: </span>Academic</p>
</div>
```

how to get email from these in above span tags...

```
<span>paola.alberti@istitutotumori.mi.it</span>
```

Comment: Post the HTML code *as a code* please, the tags got removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using XPath:

```
email = response.xpath('//li[@class="email"]/a/span/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Consider also accepting the answer, so it has resolved status.